# How to make XML element different with end element?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need send the XML that vendor asked as below.

```
<Start>
    <Ele extraAtt="123" extraAtt2="456">
        <Field1>1</Field1>
        <Field2>2/Field2>
        <Field3>3</Field3>
    </Ele>
</Start>
```

Here are my code:

```
Dim ms As MemoryStream = Nothing
Dim XMLWrt As XmlTextWriter = Nothing
Dim XMLDoc As XmlDocument = Nothing

ms = New MemoryStream()
XMLWrt = New XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8)
XMLWrt.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
XMLWrt.WriteStartDocument()

XMLWrt.WriteStartElement("Start")
XMLWrt.WriteStartElement("Ele")
AddElement(XMLWrt, "Field1", 1)
AddElement(XMLWrt, "Field2", 2)
AddElement(XMLWrt, "Field3", 3)
XMLWrt.WriteEndElement()
XMLWrt.WriteEndElement()

XMLWrt.Flush()

XMLDoc = New XmlDocument()
ms.Position = 0
XMLDoc.Load(ms)
XMLWrt.Close()
```

This code would generate the result as below.

As you can see, it missed "extraAtt="123" extraAtt2="456" on the Ele block.

I wonder how to modify code to generate what I want?

```
<Start>
    <Ele> --> I need <Ele extraAtt="123" extraAtt2="456"> instead.
        <Field1>1</Field1>
        <Field2>2/Field2>
        <Field3>3</Field3>
    </Ele>
</Start>
```

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a couple of calls on `XMLWrt.WriteAttributeString()`.

Answer (score 0):

So much easier with [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.7) IMHO.  The field values could have been entered in the declaration but I chose this way so you would get a feel for the capabilities.

```
    Dim xe As XElement = <Start>
                             <Ele>
                                 <Field1></Field1>
                                 <Field2></Field2>
                                 <Field3></Field3>
                             </Ele>
                         </Start>

    Dim ctr As Integer = 1
    For Each el As XElement In xe.<Ele>.Elements
        el.Value = ctr.ToString
        ctr += 1
    Next
    xe.<Ele>.@extraAtt = "123"
    xe.<Ele>.@extraAtt2 = "123"
    Stop 'look at xe
```

To save your work there is [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.save?view=netframework-4.7).  There is a load method also.